# I have this ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'pyparsing' I try to install pytest in Mac os

Tags: python, pytest, pyparsing

I try to install **pytest** in terminal Mac Os, so I follow the instruccions of this website Exercism     *  **https://exercism.io/tracks/python/tests**

The download starts well:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-AppleSSD:~ root# pip3 install pytest pytest-cache
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

Collecting pytest
  Downloading pytest-4.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (231 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 231 kB 711 kB/s 
Collecting pytest-cache
  Downloading pytest-cache-1.0.tar.gz (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2>=2.2.0; python_version < "3.6" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pytest) (2.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.5.0 in /Library/
```

I try to install PYTEST in terminal Mac Os, everything goes well but in this part stop the download.

It is in this part where I get an error from the download:

```
Attempting uninstall: pyparsing

    Found existing installation: pyparsing 2.0.1

ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'pyparsing'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which Python versions do you have installed, where? The error message about Python 2 should only be visible if you are actually installing Python 2 packages. The paths look like `pip3` found libraries installed by the OS in `/Library/` which is weird. Which OS version are you on and how did you install Python 3 if it's not supplied by the OS?

Comment: I have catalina in mac os pro 2012 and if I have installed python 3 in the terminal
How can I solve this problem? :(

Comment: "I have installed Python 3 in the terminal" is wayyy too vague. Installed how, where? Please [edit] your question; see also the [help] and in particular [How to ask.](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: More generally you should probably not install random libraries system-wide; instead, create a virtual environment for each project.